# Reading the contents of the dynamically created buffer giving wrong address of memory for second call to function

Tags: c++, winapi, stream, buffer

Using Visual c++  i am trying to read an image from the stream I do this by storing the stream in a buffer. I know that at what location in buffer i have the image.(its the first file in the stream and i know the size of the image so i read and store the image in buffer until the size of file and thats correct.I am sure about it) For the first time when i read the image there is no  problem it works correctly. The code is as follows-

```
ReadFromStream(IStream *pStream )
 {//this pStream  stream contents the file contents
        ULONG  cbRead;
        int size=5348928;
        char *buffer = new char[size + 1];
        HRESULT hr = pStream->Read(buffer, size, &cbRead ); //here we store the stream in buffer.Now all the data is in buffer.
        buffer[cbRead ] = L'\0';
        int location = 512 ;
        char FileContents[107643];
        memcpy(FileContents,&buffer[location],SizeOfFile); // here i have the contents of the image in File contents.I am sure about it its location. For the first call to ReadFromStream() function it works fine.
             }
```

But my situation is that i have to read the image second time also on the same execution of the program. so what happens when the second time i call to ReadFromStream() function(with the same stream value i can see on debugging the stream value is same.) even then the buffer show the contents which are at location far away from the image stored in it (i mean the stream had Image File as the first file but in the second call to ReadFromStream() the buffer points to the data of another file but the first file   was actually the image file). So the quetion is how this memory is alloctaed up to this unexpected file ?

Why the buffer shows the data which is at location very far from the starting index.(For the second call to ReadFromStream() also it should show image file as the starting file. why it show the file which is far away from the Image file ??? ) As I guess some memory is allocated and which must be deleted ?? but where and how i don't know ..am i right ??

may be its because in the second call to ReadFromStream(); this buffer has already some memory allocated i mean for the second call the buffer points to address which don't start from zero (but it should do it as i think)

Comment: No you haven't understood my question properly.Please read again.This "location" has nothing to do with my question. my question is when i second tile i call the ReadFromStream(with same Stream Value); then buffer should give the image(which was the first file) but it is giving some file far away the Image file.

Comment: @Jrol is it possible to delete the memory allocated by int size=5348928; ??? may be its because in th esecond call to ReadFromStream(); this buffer has already somememory allocated i mean for the second call the buffer points to address which don't start from zero.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you've made a really crazy assumption. Once you `delete[]` the buffer, it's gone, along with the data it contained. You absolutely can't expect that the next call to `new` will give you the same buffer and data back.

Comment: Also, your FileContents - array will be destroyed at the end of the function (when it leaves the scope). unless you do something with it before then, the data will be gone.

Comment: actually wheni call the ReadFromStream() second time with same value then the buffer will allocate the memory again so there is no problem as i guess with delete[]buffer. and the most important thing you can see is that even i have deleted the memory allocated to buffer even then buffer don't show the first file contents it show the file far away from the image file(which is the first file in the stream).And thats the question .. why it do so?? it should image file in the second call when i pass the same stream value in the second call after the deleting the buffer memory in the first call.

Comment: @Jork and @ Hulk ...Ok i have removed delete[] buffer; but even after doing this the output is still the same on debugging.

Comment: Now you've made it worse - you have built a memory leak. Every call of ReadFromStream now allocates a buffer using `new`but it never gets deleted...

Comment: Are you resetting the stream position via `IStream::Seek`? If so, are you checking that it succeeds? Not all streams support seeking.

Comment: Where does the offset `location = 512` come from? Is that some kind of header that you want to skip? Is that offset always correct between two consecutive files? And you are just creating a local `char FileContents[107643];` in each call, which will be automatically destroyed at the end of the function. What do you expect to happen? How should any of the information survive the end of the function, in your opinion?

Comment: @Jonathan Potter ..It seems that you have understood my problem correctly(not others) .No i am not using any such pointer("seek").Any idea about how to reset the stream.I think thats the problem i have i am not resetting the stream to point it to starting index to use it for second call. How to do that ??

Comment: @hulk yes i m working on tar file header.I am skipping the code between the memcpy(FileContents..)and delete function.here i have used file contents.so there is no problem with delete for me.but i don't know why each time you go to these extra things . why don't you go to my question which is "why not on the second call to ReadFromStream(with same stream variable); takes me at the starting index of the buffer?? why it skips large amount of memory and shows the data which is somewhere in middle of my stream ??" Have you understood the question? if not ?? then please see the comment of Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are like normal files in that they're sequential in nature and once you've read data, the "read cursor" is advanced and another call to `Read()` will read more data, and so on.

To seek backwards to re-read the same data again, use `IStream::Seek()`. For example, to go back to the start of the stream:

```
LARGE_INTEGER li = { 0 };
HRESULT hr = pStream->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
```

Not all streams support seeking so you should always check the return code for error.